# Grails command object temporary field validation

Tags: validation, grails, command-objects

I have a user registration form where the fields are validated using command object. One of the fields is a checkbox, which must checked before proceeding the registration, and it isn't saved to the domain object. This checkbox has a corresponding Boolean field in the command object. When checkbox is not checked, a validation error is thrown from a custom validator.

The problem is, that this error is not propagated in the `<g:renderErrors bean="${command}" as="xml"/>` block (the validator is fired correctly).

The command object:

```
class RegisterCommand {

...
Boolean termsChecked
...
static constraints = {
    ...
    termsChecked validator: RegisterController.termsCheckedValidator
}
```

Validator:

```
static final termsCheckedValidator = {termsChecked, command, errors ->
    if (!command.termsChecked) {
        return 'registerCommand.termsChecked.required'
    }
}
```

Checkbox in the GSP file:

```
<g:checkBox value="${command.termsChecked}" bean="${command}" name='termsChecked'/>
```

How this could be solved?

Comment: Is the validator in `RegisterController` as you have shown and used in question?

Comment: @dmahapatro, yes. Validation passes correctly, but the error message is never returned to the view.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you pass 3 parameters to the validator with the last one being `errors` then the return code is ignored thinking that the Spring Errors is taking care of errors.

If you want to use the error code then just pass 2 parameter to the validator as

```
static final termsCheckedValidator = {termsChecked, command ->
    if (!command.termsChecked) {
        return ['required.termsChecked']
    }
}


//messages.properties
registerCommand.termsChecked.required.termsChecked=blah
```

Comment: Thanks for your response. I removed the `errors` variable, and now after form submission I'm getting the following message: `URI
/projectName/register/register
Class
groovy.lang.MissingMethodException
Message
No signature of method: static org.apache.commons.lang.StringEscapeUtils.escapeXml() is applicable for argument types: (java.lang.Boolean) values: [false] Possible solutions: escapeXml(java.lang.String), escapeXml(java.io.Writer, java.lang.String), escapeHtml(java.lang.String), escapeSql(java.lang.String)` Edit: getting errors in `list` format works fine, but i need them in xml.

Comment: @cNduo Try a different variety of message key. Also note to return as `list`. See my update.

Comment: Your update indeed solves the problem, but only if the error output format is `list`. What about the `xml` format? Because I'm still getting the same error as in my first comment.